# Ubuntu desktop 16.4 64bit install on raid 0

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

Can any one please help. I would like to install Ubuntu 16.4 on raid 0 (I know how to set up raid through my bios, done it with Win7 and no issues), but every method I have looked up and tried to install Ubuntu on raid fails to boot. Can anyone please help (as I have pipe dreams on running Ubuntu off of lots of hdd's on raid 0, cos which compute geek wouldn't)

Comment: When you say "RAID 0" do you mean "Intel Fake RAID"? : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_with_Fake_RAID

Comment: I'm not sure, basically I go into my bios and set configure hard drive(s) as raid, restart my computer and hold down Ctrl+I and set up my raid in that menu as raid 0 (for performance as raid 1 is just a mirror of the hdd's) selecting which of my hdds to use. Once ive done that I run Ubuntu 16.4 from a usb and try to install on to my raid disk a just setup.

Comment: Do you have a laptop? Does it have mSata SSD? If so Intel Fake Raid 0 can be used with "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" (IRST) in Windows to accelerate HDD through SSD for 5 to 10x's greater speed. In Linux though we have to use EnhanceIO (not well supported anymore) or bcache, etc. for HDD to SSD caching.

Comment: No I'm using a pc, built from scratch, not having anything to do with windows at all. I can set my raid up through my mother boards bios (I'm not using a pci card or anything, all hdd's connect through my mobo's sata ports) and 3 x 250gig hdd which do show up as a 750gig disk in the Ubuntu install.

Comment: Got it. No experience with your particular environment but I'm uoviting your question to draw attention.

Comment: Thanks man, any help on this will be much appreciated. Searched high and low for an answer to this so guessing there must be a few people having this issue.

Comment: Any progress on this? My experience is also that the install is successful but I can't boot it.